# Если НЕ одно из двух определённых значений, то умолчание. Как сделать это в PHP?

Tags: php, булева-алгебра, логические-выражения

Мой скрипт на PHP принимает два языковых значения - `&lang=ru` или `&lang=en`. Если параметр `lang` явно не указан **или** равен *любому другому значению*, то значение по умолчанию должно быть установлено в `en`. Я несколько раз прочитал документацию по логическим операторам в PHP, но так и не могу понять, как реализовать проверку

> если **не** ((lang = "en") или (lang = "ru")) тогда lang = "en"

на PHP. На привычном мне Паскале я легко делаю вот так:

```
if not ((lang = 'en') or (lang = 'ru')) then lang := 'en';
```

Я потратил уйму времени, пытаясь реализовать эту нехитрую конструкцию на PHP, но у меня ничего не получается. Силюсь понять что я делаю не так вот в этом коде:

```
if (!(($lang == "en") || ($lang == "ru"))) {
  $lang = "en";
};
```

**Решение проблемы**

После того, как Anton Shchyrov указал, что логическое выражение совершенно правильное, я начал отлаживать скрипт и нашел ошибку.

Через полсотни строк я не заметил ошибку, характерную для тех, у кого нет опыта программирования на языках, по синтаксису похожих на C/C++/PHP. Ниже проблемный кусок кода, который останавливает шоу:

```
$Link = "https://www.domain.dummy/page.html;
if ($lang = "ru") {
  $Link = str_replace("dummy", "ru", $Link);
} else {
  $Link = str_replace("dummy", "co.uk", $Link);
}
```

Присвоение значения переменной в условии `if ()` не может не впечатлять, но из-за этого скрипт, разумеется, "снесло".

Не знаю как поступить в данном случае - следует ли попросить закрыть вопрос или оставить его?

Comment: Все так. Что не работает?

Comment: Хм... `if (!in_array($lang, ['es', 'en', 'ru'])) $lang = "en";`

Comment: Пока я писал обновление, тут насыпалась куча ответов, один изящнее другого! Я благодарен всем, ответившим, но могу выбрать, увы, только один.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ну раз уж все в ответы пишут=)

```
if (!in_array($lang, ['es', 'en', 'ru', 'fr'])) $lang = "en";
```

Любое количество предопределённых языков в одном условии.

А ещё можно тернарно

```
$lang = in_array($lang, ['es', 'en', 'ru', 'fr']) ? $lang : "en";
```

Список предопределяемых языков это массив который можно хранить в переменной

```
$langs = ['es', 'en', 'ru', 'fr'];
// Аналогично
$langs = array('es', 'en', 'ru', 'fr');
```

Comment: Все ответы очень классные. Спасибо. Под мой тип мышления больше всего подходит ваш ответ. Хотя, `$lang = $lang !== 'ru'? 'en': 'ru'; ` - это, конечно, бомба! :) Но пока она за пределами моего понимания...

Comment: @InterfaceUnknown, стоит почитать по тернарный оператор

Comment: Ну думаю стоит в кратце объяснить `$elem = condition == true ? "true" : "false";` Когда условие(condition) истинно выполняется действие за знаком `?` если ложно то за знаком `:`

Answer (score 4):

> Мой скрипт на PHP принимает два языковых значения - &lang=ru или &lang=en. Если параметр lang явно не указан или равен любому другому значению, то значение по умолчанию должно быть установлено в en.

Дефольтный язык `en`, если задан `ru` то язык будет `ru`.

```
$lang = !isset($lang) || $lang !== 'ru'? 'en': 'ru'; 

echo $lang;
```

Comment: Потрясающе красиво! Да уж... у PHP феноменальные возможности...

Comment: @in ничего красивого в этом коде нету, так как в случае когда "Если параметр lang явно не указан" будет ошибка типа NOTICE Undefined variable: lang

Comment: @MykolaVeriga теперь уже нет, так что можете отзывать свой минус.

Answer (score 3):

:D Раз уж такая движуха... Сложно было придумать что-то новенькое, но я справился:

```
switch ($lang) {
    case 'ru':
    case 'en':
        break;
    default:
        $lang = 'en';
        break;
}
```

Comment: На свитче вообще неожиданно=)))))))

Comment: Старый-добрый switch )) Я пока не дошел до него в документации - сегодня всего лишь неделя, как я изучаю PHP. Спасибо +1